# Apppend log message at beginning of file log4j

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

**1.** I am trying to add log message at beginning of file so that I can see latest message first on log file.

**2.** I want to add month and year after log file but I am not getting that in current active file. eg - test_2015-04-22.log

property file is given below -

```
log4j.appender.APP=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.APP.File=${catalina.base}/logs/test.log
log4j.appender.APP.Append=true
log4j.appender.APP.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.APP.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM
log4j.appender.APP.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.APP.layout.ConversionPattern =%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} - %m%n
log4j.appender.APP.filePattern =Test_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
```

Comment: Can you close this if any of the below answered your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question shows a log4j-1.2 configuration, but since the question also has a log4j2 tag, I feel free to answer this by showing you how to accomplish this with log4j2.

In [log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), you can declare a [property](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution) that formats the date, then use this property to configure your appender file name.

Also, you can use the `header` attribute of the [pattern layout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) to set a header that is output at the beginning of a file. For [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) this header will be output on every rollover.

Use one of the [lookups](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) built-in to log4j2 to dynamically change the output of your header at rollover time.

Example:

```
<Configuration status="WARN"><!-- use TRACE to troubleshoot your config if needed-->
  <Properties>
    <property name="yyyyMMdd">${date:yyyyMMdd}</property>
  </Properties>

  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="Application" 
            fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/test${sys:yyyyMMdd}.log"
            filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout header="File: ${main:--file}">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} - %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  <Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Application" />
    </root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: how can we write in .property instead of .xml?

Comment: Log4j2 does not support the .properties config format.

Comment: How can I make a custom header for every file?

Comment: Not date and so on, but to make a counter of users that come from java

Answer (score 1):

1. it's not possible , think of the file as a stack which respects LAST In FIRST Out which makes perfect sense when debugging to see the last message at the end.
2. The log for today will have the name `test.log` but tomorrow it will be renamed to `Test_2015-04-22.log`

Comment: I have already old system which have that feature. thats why its important to implement the same

Comment: both of them are there

Comment: and how do you write the last message at the beginning of the file? creating a new file write last message and the the content from the old file ?

Comment: Its already implemented there and I have to implemet the same.